# How to show that $\pm \langle Tx, x \rangle \leq M \|x\|^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis

In our introductory functional analysis course, we defined the norm of a bounded operator $T \in B(H)$ as $$ \|T\| := \sup_{\| x \| \leq 1} \|T(x)\|. $$

However, there is now a lemma saying:

**Lemma:** Let $T \in B(H)$ be self-adjoint. Then $$ \| T\| = \sup \left\{ | \langle Tx, x \rangle | \ | x \in H, \| x\| \leq 1 \right\}. $$

For the proof, one part of the inequality I understand. We let $$ M = \sup \left\{ | \langle Tx, x \rangle | \ | x \in H, \| x\| \leq 1 \right\}. $$ Then I have that by Cauchy-Schwarz $$ | \langle Tx, x \rangle | \leq \| T(x)\| \ \| x \| \leq \| T \| \ \| x \|^2. $$ Taking this for all $x \in H$ with $\| x \| \leq 1$, we see that $M \leq \| T\|. $

However, in my course notes, in order to prove that $M \geq \|T\|$, the claim is being made that **the following holds**: $$ \pm \langle Tx, x \rangle \leq M \|x\|^2.$$ (Since $T$ is self-adjoint, $\langle Tx, x \rangle \in \mathbb{R}$ and this makes sense).

One then uses this in the inequalities $$\langle T(x+y), x+y \rangle \leq M \|x+y\|^2 \\ - \langle T(x-y), x-y\rangle \leq M \|x-y\|^2$$ adds these to take the real part, and then one arrives at the desired conclusion.

**My question** is, how to prove that $$ \pm \langle Tx, x \rangle \leq M \|x\|^2.$$

Comment: You can use `\cdot` to denote multiplication. For example, instead of $\| T \| \ \| x \|^2$ you can write $\|T\| \cdot \|x\|^2$ using `$\|T\| \cdot \|x\|^2$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}x=\la y$ where $\la=\|x\|$ and so $\|y\|=1$. Then
$$|\left<Ty,y\right>|\le M$$
by definition of $M$. Then
$$|\left<Tx,x\right>|=
|\left<\la Ty,\la y\right>|=\la^2|\left<Ty,y\right>|\le M\la^2=M\|x\|^2.$$

Comment: Extraordinary! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, for any non-zero element $y \in H$, the element $x = \frac{y}{\| y\|}$ is of norm 1.
Then write
$$
\left| \langle T \frac{y}{\| y\|}, \frac{y}{\| y\|} \rangle \right| \leq M
$$
Use the linearity of $T$ to move the norms in the right hand side.